# Using a combobox to query the database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have all the days of the week in a combobox, yet when selecting a day all the days are shown in my data grid... How can I use the one selected value from the combobox to search just that value.

```
Private Sub btnViewTimeTable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnViewTimeTable.Click

    If (cbDay.Text = "Monday" Or cbDay.Text = "Tuesday" Or cbDay.Text = "Wednesday" Or cbDay.Text = "Thursday" Or cbDay.Text = "Friday" Or cbDay.Text = "Saturday" Or cbDay.Text = "Sunday") Then
        Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT Time, Activity, Equipment FROM TimeTable WHERE Day = cbDay"
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlQuery, conn)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Table")
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("Table")

        With DGTimeTable
            .AutoGenerateColumns = True
            .DataSource = ds
            .DataMember = "Table"
        End With

        With DGTimeTable
            .Columns(0).Width = 108
            .Columns(1).Width = 154
            .Columns(2).Width = 278
            Me.DGTimeTable.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
            Me.DGTimeTable.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
        End With

    Else
        MsgBox("Please Select a Day!")

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Simply make a filter in your datagridview using following code

```
Dim column As String = 'Your weekday column Name in Datagridview
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim rows = ds.Tables(0).Select("Convert(" & column & ", 'System.String') LIKE '*" + ComboBox1.SelectedItem + "*'")

    Try
        DGTimeTable.DataSource = rows.CopyToDataTable
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing cbDay as a string, try changing this line

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT Time, Activity, Equipment FROM TimeTable WHERE Day = cbDay"
```

to something like this

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = String.Format("SELECT Time, Activity, Equipment FROM TimeTable WHERE Day = {0}", cbDay.Text)
```